# How to use Mailchimp API re-send opt in email to pending list members

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3

I'm trying to use the v3 API to trigger a re-send of the opt-in mail for users already in the pending status. When using the PUT or PATCH requests (to `3.0/lists/<list id>/members/<member hash>`), that doesn't trigger a opt-in email. But as I understand, this would be the expected behavior?

Is there possibly some throttling mechanism in place that doesn't allow re-requesting an opt-in mail in a certain time frame?